# ListView FindControl error

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, findcontrol

I have the next error:

> System.NullReferenceException – Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

To the next code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LV1"  runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="100px" Height="100px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
     //....and so on till the 
</asp:ListView>
```

The code - behind:

```
protected void checkTheImage()
{
    ((Image)LV1.FindControl("Image1")).ImageUrl = "(noImage.jpg)" ;
}
```

and the code on page_load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkTheImage();
}
```

Why i got the error? what is wrong in my code?

Comment: My guess is that the ListView databinding hasn't actually happened when you call `checkTheImage()` (i.e. it's too early).  You can quickly test this by using an event which happens later in the Page lifecycle, such as Page_PreRender.  EDIT:  On second thought, that might also be too early, rather try handle the ListView.Databound event, and try your code in there.

Comment: I agree with Daniel B. You should read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls)

Comment: The problem solved when i wrote the Page_PreRender. great ! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the item:

```
protected void checkTheImage()
{
    ((Image)LV1.Items[0].FindControl("Image1")).ImageUrl = "(noImage.jpg)" ;
}
```

because the ListView render an Image1 control for each child item. To change all images:

```
protected void checkTheImage()
{
   foreach(ListViewItem item in LV1.Items)
      ((Image)item.FindControl("Image1")).ImageUrl = "(noImage.jpg)" ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. now i dont get the error... but its not display the noImage.jpg ... why?

Comment: The problem solved when i wrote the Page_PreRender. great ! thanks